# Sharing the application context inside .ear - how it is done?

Tags: spring, ear

After reading through this [article](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/11/using-a-shared-parent-application-context-in-a-multi-war-spring-application/), I am kind of confused, because I am under assumption that wars inside ear are isolated enough that they cannot talk to each other. If my assumption is correct, how could they share the application context? does spring initiate their own classloader?

Answer (score 0):

applications have their own classloader, EARs and their containing wars are belonging to the same application and can theirfor access each others classes and more specifically singletons. I could not found a better description but **[this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/programming/classloading.html#1073493)** is how weblogic handles it.